# Is there a module for site explanation messages?

Tags: 7, forms

Many sites have text areas which appear to explain things to new users. With an option to hide the message in future.

I haven't seen such a module for Drupal, does one exist?

I have tried googling but to be honest I have no idea what terminology to use when searching for one.

Answer (score 1):

The closest module I know is the [Legal module](http://drupal.org/project/legal), this is more for showing the terms of service or similar for users before registering, but it might be close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks, we're already using that for T&Cs, and we are looking for something which would work per path.

Answer (score 1):

The [Advanced Help Injection and Export](http://drupal.org/project/helpinject) module is probably what you are looking for.

From project page, "This module assists you in writing help texts suitable for use with the Advanced Help module by allowing you to write your help texts in Drupal books. Once you've written the help texts you can inject help icons into any page, form or form item, linking them to the book page that should later appear. The final step is to export all of the help texts as well as the injection data into a new module consisting of Advanced Help files and a simple generated module. The module has all of the information needed to inject the help icons into the right pages, forms, and form elements. The new generated module is ready for distribution as a standalone project or a submodule in a larger project."

Comment: That looks like a great module, which I may also use, but not quite what I am after. I'm looking for something which works on a page level and is intrusive and turn off able. I may do something myself as a context plugin.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe something that is just uses context and collapsible blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jeremy: I use a very simple jquery routine to create what you appear to be seeking. The idea is to place "teaser" explainer text on the various pages, with embedded links that trigger a jquery in-place expansion of the additional information.

For example, some initial high level explainer text appears below a form widget, with a link at the end of that one line beneath the form widget saying "more detail please"; clicking that link causes additional markup of any sort to expand in place where ever on the page you want it - with other elements moving aside to make room.

After expansion, that markup can contain additional links that also expand in place.

Using my super simple routine, one can create a single hierarchical page with dynamic, collapsing divs showing and hiding information complexity at will. Once you start using it, the finished pages really feel like how the web was original described (to me) as a hierarchical information platform - which hardly anyone actually implements.

Anyway: this logic is tiny, easy to use, and you can dink around with in and tell if it will do what you need in 30 minutes.
http://www.missingubercartmanual.com/The-Basics-of-using-Java-Script-in-Drupal

I describe the code on a tutorial page for understanding how to use Java Script in Drupal.