# How to add explanation text/link to selection options in views page

Tags: views

First my apologies for my probably stupid question, but I can't find an answer on this one:

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have created a page with news articles based on Views. On top of the list of news items there are 2 options to filter that list of items: First a pull-down menu with a list of products the news items could be linked. The other option it to type one or more tags. One can also use a combination of those two.

This is rather straight forward for me, but I'm expecting our users would need some explanation.

How can I add a small piece of text right of the selections options (containing a link with an explanation page) ?

I found this message on this site, but without clear explanation how to build something like this: [Is there a module for site explanation messages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/is-there-a-module-for-site-explanation-messages)

Comment: Your filtering options are in fact the view's exposed filters? If this is the case, when you set this filter you have the option of adding a description under the field's Label

Comment: Yes my filtering options are exposed. I tried to enter the description, which worked fine, but it's getting a rather long sentence. I prefer the option to add text on the right and able to contain a link to a more detailed explanation.